# Was there a midnight launch for the death of Superman in 1993?

Tags: dc, superman

I happen to remember where I was when Superman "died."  As a teenager, I was at a planning meeting for an organization I was involved in, and as it broke up, somebody noticed that it was past midnight, and thus the day of Superman's death had arrived.

Not being a Superman fan specifically, I had been generally aware the the death of the Man of Steel was coming up, but I didn't know anything else beyond that.  It was not until about a year or so later that I read the *Death of Superman* collection that followed his running battle with Doomsday.  However, as our meeting was breaking up, there was suddenly a great deal of discussion about the big comic event that day.  I got the impression that there was to have been some kind of midnight promotion event, but I am not sure what form it might have taken.  (This was a bit before midnight premieres for highly anticipated movies, which seem to have begun in earnest with the *Star Wars* re-releases a few years later.)  So was it just that comic book stores were going to be open at midnight to start selling *Superman* #75 that night, or was there a more elaborate midnight promotion?

Comment: There's a nice commentary from a guy working at a comic-stall [here](http://generaldouchebaggery.blogspot.com/2012/04/heroland-issue-2-dork-knight-returns.html). It certainly doesn't look like there was a midnight opening. There were people queuing at dawn

Comment: And from another perspective. Again, no midnight opening; https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHfKU.png

Comment: I don't remember one. And, I don't think the event really hit the news until the day of release, rather than before it.